# From daily returns to weekly returns with NA

Tags: r, return, na, missing-data, weekday

I have a dataset with daily returns and I would like to transform them in weekly returns.
I tried

```
RetW = apply.weekly(Yxts, Return.cumulative, geometric=T)
```

and the results are correct if I do not have missing values. However, in case of `NA` for an entire week, I get a zero and this would introduce bias in my analysis.

Do you have any suggestions regarding how to move from daily to weekly returns avoiding that missing values are replaced by a zero? Many thanks

Comment: obviously you are using a function apply.weekly() which is not part of my standard vocab in R. From your problem statement think about how to deal with the NAs, e.g. remove them from your data, imput them, or even set them to zero. As you describe the function apply.weekly() returns 0 for NAs, this way you supply a valid dataset to the function.

Comment: Unfortunately, I must have NA rather 0 in the dataset because it would underestimate the returns in my dataset setting them to 0. Would you suggest an alternative to the function apply. weekly?

Comment: It is difficult to state when not knowing how your data looks like. You will find a lot of friends here, if you provide a small reproducible example to get you going.    ----   I am assuming your data comes with dates (or at least a time index) and associated measurement value. Binning into groups (e.g. weeks) can be readily done with the tidyverse, groups like weeks (or other time increments) you can get with the help of lubridate. Having control over your processing (function) allows you to also handle the NAs (ignore, impute, or set to 0).

Comment: I finally had a minute to google and check the documentation. Obviously, you have to think about how to deal with your missing data, e.g. impute estimates. The function PerformanceAnalytics::Return.cumulative() calculates the product of each period return. Strictly speaking it should return NA when facing a NA and not 0. If setting NAs to 0 skews your results, a way to compensate for this is to impute a value. There are many ways of doing this, for a start I would use a simple mean between the previous and next value. Of course you can do more sophisticated things like using rolling medians.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem. It is true that Return.cumulative() "skews" the results the moment you add NAs to your returns. However, I can only produce a 0, if the whole 1st week is NA. setting other weeks to NA you get "skewed" results. Dealing with the 0 / 1st week problem: do you need the week? just remove it from your returns. For the other weeks, it may help to split your returns into a set of complete and continuous weeks. This way Return.cumulative() should produce the correct results for that period. Correct the start value if you need to account for earlier returns.